# How mono runtime is embbedded into Android application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

As far as I understand, applications built with Xamarin deploy in every application a mono runtime that works beside the ART, communicating between each other.

Knowing the current android limitations that starting `API-28` you cannot start binaries, I was wondering how actually the runtime gets started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is briefly described in the Xamarin docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/internals/architecture#application-startup

If you take a look at the build output of your app in `obj/Debug/android/src/mono` you will notice a couple of java files.

**MonoRuntimeProvider.java**

This creates a ContentProvider, which is responsible for launching the mono runtime and starting your App.

**MonoPackageManager_Resources.java**

This class is called by the MonoRuntimeProvider, which is a helper class to find the Assembly containing your App.

The MonoRuntimeProvider is registered in the AndroidManifest.xml in the Application tag. Which means that when your App starts, the Content provider will also start, and in turn starts the Mono Runtime.

At build time Android Callable Wrappers (ACW) are generated for your Activities (and many other types as well). This is a way to invoke managed (C# code) from the Android world.

If you try to decompile your App, you will see that in the constructor of such ACW's there is a call to the mono runtime register and activate the managed type.

As for the limitations in API-28, I don't see anywhere in the docs where they mention anything about not being able to start binaries.
There are some [Restrictions on non-SDK interfaces](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces#feature-request). If it was the case that you were not able to consume binaries in your Android App it would mean that all Apps consuming C/C++ NDK libraries would be broken.
There has been some limitations to where you can access such libraries. In the past you would be able to use some binaries outside of your Applications scope, which were bundled with Android, this is not allowed anymore and you need to bundle this with your App yourself.